# How to successfully make a hive jdbc call inside a mapper in MR job where the cluster is secured by Kerberos

Tags: jdbc, mapreduce, hive, kerberos

I am writing a utility that is a map reduce job where the reducer makes calls to various databases and Hive is one of them.

Our cluster is kerberized. 
I am doing kinit before kicking off the MR job, but when the reducer runs, it fails with an error "No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)"

This indicates that it doesnt have a valid ticket. I tried to get a delegation token for Hive service in the MR driver, but it failed because the Hive service account is not allowed to impersonate my user.

I don't want to copy the keytab file onto all worker nodes, I want to somehow make either delegation token work or pass the credentials from MR driver to the mappers & reducers.

Can anyone suggest another method to get a valid ticket in the mappers & reducers to make Hive JDBC calls.

Thanks,
Arun.

Comment: Delegation tokens work for HDFS and YARN. Full stop. They are not supported by HiveServer2, by the Metastore, by HBase, by ZooKeeper, by Oozie, *<insert your favorite software here>*. **You have no choice, just ship a keytab to the Mappers and Reducers** - then either you bootstrap a `UserGroupInformation` or you set up some raw JAAS configuration *(HS2 uses Thrift and Thrift uses JAAS)*.

Comment: By the way, Kerberos was designed for P2P communication. It was never supposed to authenticate a client against a *cluster* of machines -- or a cluster of clients against a service (as in your case). That's why Hadoop introduced the delegation tokens. But in way, that's defeating the purpose of secure authentification...

Comment: Thank you Samson for the response. I have shipped the keytab file from Edge node using MR driver to Mappers with job.addCacheFile(),
and attempted to login using keytab, in my mapper code. Here is the code that I used to login with keytab.
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication","Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
File keytabFile = new File("keytab");
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user@REALM.COM",keytabFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: After that I have seen a message in the log "org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user user@REALM using keytab file '/local/path/to/keytab'. My next line of code is to connect to Hive via JDBC, but I still get the same kerberos error.  I am not sure why it would fail after successfully logging in with keytab.   I ran sample Hive JDBC java code on Edge node, and it works fine with the "loginUserFromKeytab" approach. I did "kdestroy" on edge node to make sure there is no valid ticket and ran my code on edge node, and it worked fine. It doesnt work on mappers

Comment: Hmmm... I would bet that the UGI has created a "private" TGT and did not store it in the default cache, so that Thrift (which is not aware of the UGI) cannot use that TGT. Activate the debugging traces with `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` plus JVM props `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: Actually I never tried the UGI + JDBC combination, only the raw JAAS conf +JDBC (for connecting from outside the cluster, without the clutter of Hadoop dependencies) and the UGI + ZK +HBase.

Comment: BTW, now that you are messing with Kerberos, this GitBook is a must-read: https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/ugi.html

Comment: Thanks Samson. The debug options are not being propagated to mappers/reducers. I m trying to get debug turned on in my reducers.    The loginUserFromKeytab() approach worked fine on edge node.  Is there a way I can verify whether ticket cache is not being stored on worker nodes ? Or, if I can hard code KRB5CCNAME and force the ticket cache to be stored on the worker nodes on that path ? would it make the UGI work ?  And thank you for the gitbook.  I will also explore  JAAS/GSS API + JAAS conf + JDBC as it seems to have worked for you.

Comment: *¨debug options are not being propagated¨* -- you have to **set** them explicitly; look into properties `mapreduce.admin.user.env` and `mapreduce.map.java.opts` / `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` and how you can inject additional stuff (without trashing the defaults)

Comment: Now that I think of it, you might try a quick-and-dirty fix: on Mapper/Reducer initialization, *(a)* set env variable KRB5CCNAME to a file in your private container space, e.g.`FILE:./krb5cc_local` *(b)* spawn a sub-process (which inherits all your env. variables) to run `kinit` *(c)* open the JDBC connection, which will find the TGT just created by kinit. Dirty, yes, but even the Hadoop authentication library uses a spawn `kinit` in some cases, with a comment that *"everything else that uses JAAS failed"* (cf. known issue about ticket renewal in Java)

Comment: @Samson, Thank you so much for your time and help. I am able to get past kerberos authentication error by passing the jaas.conf, keytab file from the Driver to my reducers using distributed cache. Now, I am able to make Hive JDBC calls from my reducers without any kerberos errors. I am still exploring ways to make the loginUserFromKeytab() and delegation tokens work for my use case.

Comment: I am able to use jaas.conf with the option "useTicketCache=true" so that I dont have to pass on the keytab file all over the cluster. All I have to do is give the path of ticket cache in jaas.conf against "ticketCache" property.

Comment: @IWonderHow I am facing the similar issue you have faced. But in my case, its not Map-reduce job. can you paste the sample code of yours like how you used Distributed cache. It will be helpful for me.